# Restrict unix user from setting environment variables during the active session

Tags: environment-variables

I have a situation in which I want to restrict a Unix user from setting up environment variables or modifying the environment variables locally during the user's active Unix session.

For example, if I've set my
`JAVA_HOME='/usr/java'`
then I would like to make sure the user will not be able to change/modify it during his login.

I did a workaround to set this up via `/etc/security/limits.conf`, but this setting will only restrict the use of that command locally. I don't want to restrict the use of that command(`export` in this case), but rather restrict the use of that command specifically for modifying certain environment variables.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

```
export MYENV=value
readonly MYENV
```

Check [Protected environment variables?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/137337/protected-environment-variables) (also on unix.stackexchange.com)

Comment: This is shell-dependent.  In `bash` this is permanent.  `zsh` lets you undo this.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: A new shell session started from that shell would inherit the value of `MYENV`, but would not inherit the read-only attribute set on the variable. The user would therefore be able to modify the variable by simply starting a new shell.